More efficient way to loop through lines and duplicate if a certain character is found
I have around 3K rows of data imported from Microsoft Planner.
In the column "Assigned to", there are lines that contain strings like: "Employee A; Employee B; Employee C".
I want to find these lines and duplicate them so that they become (in this example) three lines: "Employee A" "Employee B" "Employee C".
The content of every other column is duplicated.
What I came up takes around 2-3 minutes to complete. There are approximately 3K rows at the start and I end up with 7K rows.
'=================================
'How many rows have multiple employees assigned?
'=================================
lNbLignes = tbl1lpEmploye.ListColumns("Nom du compartiment").DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Row 'Total number of rows
iColonne = tbl1lpEmploye.ListColumns("Assigned to").DataBodyRange.Column 'Column that contains the assignments

iCompteur = 0
'Count the number of rows that contain ";" in "Assigned to" and thus need to be duplicated
For I = 2 To lNbLignes
    If InStr(ws1lpEmploye.Cells(I, iColonne).Value, ";") <> 0 Then
        iCompteur = iCompteur + (Len(ws1lpEmploye.Cells(I, iColonne).Value) - Len(Replace(ws1lpEmploye.Cells(I, iColonne).Value, ";", "")))
    End If
Next I

'=================================
'Duplicate rows with multiples assignments
'=================================
iColonne = tbl1lpEmploye.ListColumns("Assigned to").DataBodyRange.Column
    
For I = 2 To (lNbLignes + iCompteur) 'Number of rows + number of rows with ";" in "Assigned to"
    iPosition = InStr(ws1lpEmploye.Cells(I, iColonne).Value, ";") '"Employee A; Employee B; Employee C"
    If iPosition <> 0 Then
        With ws1lpEmploye
            .Rows(I + 1).Insert 'Add a news row
            .Cells(I + 1, iColonne).Value2 = Mid(.Cells(I, iColonne).Value2, iPosition + 1) 'Add the name following the character ";" in the new row I+1
            .Cells(I, iColonne).Value2 = Left(.Cells(I, iColonne).Value2, iPosition - 1) 'Keep the previous name in row I
            'At this point, RowI: "Employee A"
            'Row I+1: "Employee B;Employee C". The loop will continue at I+1, so the next lines that will be looked at is this one
            For j = 1 To tbl1lpEmploye.ListColumns.Count 'Copy the content of every other column in I+1
                Select Case j
                    Case iColonne
                        'Don't do anything to the "Assigned to" column
                    Case Else
                        .Cells(I + 1, j).Value2 = .Cells(I, j).Value2 '
                End Select
             Next j
        End With
    End If
Next I

Is there a way to do this in an array and then transfer the results to the original Excel table, that would be quicker?

Basically you write your source data to an array, then walk that array to determine how many rows in your output array you'll need, resize your output array to match that size, then walk your source array to fill your output array.  Once your output array is populated, write the array to the Excel workbook using a range which matches the output array in size.  It sounds complicated, but it's actually pretty simple and is screaming fast.


Reading and writing cells on a worksheet can be time-consuming. A more efficient approach is to load the data into an array.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Split function


ListObject.DataBodyRange property (Excel)

    Set tbl1lpEmploye = Sheet1.ListObjects(1) ' for testing
    '=================================
    'How many rows have multiple employees assigned?
    '=================================
    iColonne = tbl1lpEmploye.ListColumns("Assigned to").Index 'Column index that contains the assignments
    
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iC As Long, ColCnt As Long, aStr, vStr
    ' load table into an array
    arrData = tbl1lpEmploye.DataBodyRange.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    iCompteur = 0
    'Count the number of rows in output
    For I = 1 To UBound(arrData)
        iCompteur = iCompteur + UBound(Split(arrData(I, iColonne), ";")) + 1
    Next I
    ReDim arrRes(1 To iCompteur, 1 To ColCnt)
    
    '=================================
    'Duplicate rows with multiples assignments
    '=================================
    iCompteur = 0
    ' loop through table rows
    For I = 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' split "Assigned to"
        aStr = Split(arrData(I, iColonne), ";")
        ' dubplicate rwos
        For Each vStr In aStr
            iCompteur = iCompteur + 1
            For iC = 1 To ColCnt
                If iC = iColonne Then
                    arrRes(iCompteur, iC) = vStr
                Else
                    arrRes(iCompteur, iC) = arrData(I, iC)
                End If
            Next iC
        Next
    Next I
    ' write output to sheet
    tbl1lpEmploye.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Resize(iCompteur, ColCnt).Value = arrRes



Thank you very much, this runs very fast. I find the loop for duplicating rows to the output array very elegantly written.

I used my own data, using the following method:
Dim rData As Excel.Range
Dim rw As Excel.Range
Dim rPres As Excel.Range
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim aSplit() As String

Set rData = Range("a2:f3")
Set rPres = Range("i2")

lngCounter = 0

For Each rw In rData.Rows

    aSplit = Split(rw.Columns(rw.Columns.Count).Value, ";")

    rPres.Offset(lngCounter, 0).Resize(UBound(aSplit) + 1, rw.Columns.Count - 1).Value = _
                                rw.Resize(1, rw.Columns.Count - 1).Value
    rPres.Offset(lngCounter, rw.Columns.Count - 1).Resize(UBound(aSplit) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(aSplit)

    lngCounter = lngCounter + UBound(aSplit) + 1
    
Next rw

Which gave

